# Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

Tags: apache, xampp

Помогите решить проблему с запуском Апача. Проблема: заняты порты 80, 443, замена на 8080 ничего не меняет, что такое инетинфо? За что отвечает? Как отключить?

Лог запуска

> `9:29:05  [main]   Initializing Control Panel
> 9:29:05  [main]     Windows Version: Windows XP SP3 32-bit
> 9:29:05  [main]     XAMPP Version: 1.8.1
> 9:29:05  [main]     Control Panel Version: 3.1.0 3.1.0 [ Compiled: September 20th 2012 ]
> 9:29:05  [main]     Running with Administrator rights - good!
> 9:29:05  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
> 9:29:05  [main]     Checking for prerequisites
> 9:29:05  [main]     All prerequisites found
> 9:29:05  [main]     Initializing Modules
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   Problem detected!
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   Port 80 in use by "inetinfo.exe"!
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   Problem detected!
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   Port 443 in use by "inetinfo.exe"!
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
> 9:29:05  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port`

Comment: Не ответ, т.к. отвечаю только по апачу - а что мешает использовать порт, например, 1234? Или 4321? Если они не заняты - в настройках апача поменяйте и пользуйтесь на здоровье)

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости у Вас на машине запущен IIS ( Internet Information Services) - Майкрософтовский аналог апач. Так как он также сервер, то и занимает те же порты. Навряд ли Вам он нужен, если уже решили установить апач.

Его наиболее правильно остановить через консоль. Описано [здесь](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc732317(v=ws.10).aspx).

Второй вариант - использовать IIS. Возможно, что для Ваших задач его будет предостаточно.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Перевел службы IIS в режим ручного запуска, вроде бы заработало. Ещё раз спасибо